# How do you input more than 1 character before event happens in VB.Net function Textchanged()

Tags: vb.net

Im working on a code in VB.NET wherein I scan a barcode(21 digit input) into a text box, and immediately, it’s supposed to show some data. I get the barcode input via a text box, which is supposed to contain the entire 21 digits, and I’m using the function textChanged() to see if the text box value has updated.

The problem is, the code runs after only the first value of the barcode gets read, and the rest of the values don’t reflect in the text box at all.

Is there any way I can get the entire 21 digits and then pursue the remainder of the code (note: it has to be automatic after the 21 digits are entered)

Code:

Private sub number_textChanged(sender as Object, E as EventArgs) handles number.TextChanged

If number.text.length =21 then
Value=number.text
End if

Answer (score 0):

Send your textChanged() code, in that you can count then entered valued once reached 21 count then you can show 21 digit barcode. Or you can use textbox mouseout event, in that it will wait until you enter value fully, when you mouseout from textbox, it will trigger event.

Otherwise you can use javascript to get textbox value count and show after 21 digit.

```js
function checklength() {
    var len = document.getElementById("TextBox18").value.length;
    if (len == 21) {
        alert(document.getElementById("TextBox18").value);
    }
}
```

and Textbox in source code add onkeyup event like this

```xml
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox18" onKeyUp="checklenght()"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can store that value in hidden value use in server side.

Comment: I’ve written the code into the question itself(edited). Please check that. I don’t want to use mouseOut as I want it to be an automatic call

Comment: Check above answer, updated in description.

Comment: @Andrew Morton ok , sorry for inconvenience